# ObservableCollection / ObservableRangeCollection Set is never triggered

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin-community-toolkit

I'm using lists in my program and I need the list to update without me having to set the item source to null every time I get new information.

The recommended workaround is to use an ObservableCollection, so that's what I did. Everything worked great! I called the ObservableCollection and it activated the "get {...};" and when I added or removed from the ObservableCollection it activated the "set {...};"

```
ObservableCollection<Class> list = new ObservableCollection<Class>();
public ObservableCollection<Class> List
{
     get => list;
     set 
     {
          {...}
     }
}
```

Originally I was using the standard new file version of Xamarin forms (5.0.0.2196) and Xamarin Essentials (1.7.0) to test my properties and bindings and everything worked fine.

Then I did I ruined everything by updating Xamarin forms and Xamarin Essentials to the latest versions :(

Ever since, my ObservableCollection never activates the "set {...};" code. Does anyone know how to trigger the "set" code or the On Collection Changed code?

And how should my new property constructors look?

---

[EDIT]

Thanks to the awesome responses, I got it all figured out!

To create a collection changed event, you just have to add the following code in your page constructor:

```
public PageVM 
{
     list.CollectionChanged += [Tab] or List_CollectionChanged
}

private void List_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //This Method is generated automatically by pressing [Tab]
    {...}
}
```

When the entire collection is set to a value,

```
example//

ObservableCollection<string> list = new ObservableCollection<string> ();
ObservableCollection<string> List 
{
     get => list;
     set 
     {
         list = value;
         {...}
     }
}
ObservableCollection<string> List2 = new ObservableCollection<string> { "e", "f", "g" };
List = List2
```

the "set {...};" code is called and executed. However, when the collection is "changed" with .Add() or .Remove(), the Collection Changed Event is triggered.

```
example// 

List.Add("g"); 
or
List.Remove("a");
```

Great! Everything makes sense now; right? Well, not so fast... If you try to set the value of an ObservableCollection in a method and then later in that same method add or remove a value, it won't trigger a collection changed event. Instead of automatically executing the Collection Changed event, you will have to manually add an OnPropertyChanged(nameof(List)) in the method that changed the ObservableCollection to update the UI.

```
example//

public void MethodThatChangesObservableObject()
{
     List = List1;
     //Triggers "set {...};" from constructor
     
     List.Add("w");
     List.Remove("a");
     //Neither the add or remove will trigger a collection changed event

     OnPropertyChanged(nameof(List));
     //Will make Xamarin Forms aware that the UI need to be refreshed
}
```

If you add or remove an item from the ObservableCollection before "List = List2;" everything will be triggered as expected. However, any "changes" that are made to the ObservableCollection after the value is "set" in a given method won't trigger any other events.

Thanks again to everyone who contributed to helping me solve my question! This may be quite long but I hope this will help anyone who is currently learning Xamarin Forms like I am!

Comment: Xamarin's API is frozen. If a given update breaks something that used to work, then that's a bug, and should be reported https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues. First, search for similar report. If found, add to it. Otherwise, create new `issue`. Say what version it broke in, and the previous version that worked. Give as much detail as you can. Best is a small public github repo that can be used to verify the problem.

Comment: adding/removing items from an OC does not call the `set` - it instead fires a `CollectionChanged` event.  The `set` is only called when the entire OC object is set

Comment: If you want help with OnCollectionChanged, please add the code of that method to your project, and your question. Then put a breakpoint in it. Does that breakpoint ever get reached?

Answer (score 0):

You only need to create the `ObservableCollection` once. Adding/removing items will trigger the [`CollectionChanged` event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1.collectionchanged?view=net-6.0). You can subscribe to that event to react to changes like this:

```cs
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

public class DemoViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Book> Books { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Book>();

    public DemoViewModel()
    {
        Books.CollectionChanged += Books_CollectionChanged;
    }

    private void Books_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //do something when items are added/removed
    }
}
```